# WooCommerrce settings page not found error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed WooCommerce in my website and when I try to open woocommerce settings its redirecting to website front-end with page showing error message "OOPS! THAT PAGE CAN’T BE FOUND"(Page not found). I'm using twentyseventeen theme and no other plugins. I also tried installing WooCommerce manually through FTP but still shows same error. 
[image: error page]
I think there must be some problem with permalinks or plugin. I have resaved the permalinks, but no use. Please let me know what could be the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have entered a wrong URL.

Please try with this URL /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings.

Comment: I tried it but its showing "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page." error message. Also I observed that the orders section is missing in WooCommerce.